# Validation for combination of two fields in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Can we validate combination of two fields I don't want same entry in my events table
For example

```
no | event     | category
----------------------
1  | Wedding   | Band
2  | Wedding   | Food
3  | Wedding   | Decor
4  | Wedding   | Band  // laravel validation to avoid this
```

Like unique event

```
'event' => 'required|unique:events'
```

Anything like this

```
'event' => 'required|unique:events|category:unique'
```

Comment: Have you checked my answer,@Komal?

Comment: Not yet, I'll check and let you know.. thanks @ShaunakShukla

Answer (score 3):

Below rule checks for Unique event name under given `$categoryName`. `$categoryName` can be Band, Food, Decore, any!

For example, if Event is 'Wedding' and category is 'Band', It will not let you insert, it will throw error of already exist. If Event is 'wedding' and category is 'Any', it will let you insert.

```
'event' => 'required|unique:events,event,NULL,id,category,'.$categoryName
```

You can find documentation of it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation), you have to search for keyword 'Adding Additional Where Clauses' on that page.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I ran into the same problem so here's my quick fix.
On `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`, inside the boot() method, add this:

```
Validator::extend('uniqueCombo', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

$query = DB::table($parameters[0])
    ->where($attribute, '=', $value)
    ->where($parameters[1], '=', request($parameters[1]));

if (isset($parameters[2])) {
    $query = $query->where('id', '<>', $parameters[2]);
}

return ($query->count() <= 0);
```

});

Use it like this for create:

```
'column' => 'uniqueCombo:table,other_column'
```

And like this for update:

```
'column' => 'uniqueCombo:table,other_column,instance_id'
```

Just make sure that on the request you'll have an input with `name="other_column"`.

Hope that helps someone. :)